# Spacing between plot border and start of data plotting in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

The problem starts with the fact i have a very small area to plot a chart and i need to have markers on it as well. Now because of the small area, the markers are getting cut off and they are a key piece of information. So is there any way by which i can add some spacing between the border of the plot and the actual start of the data plot itself ?

Heres a running example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/138190/charts/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `minPadding` and `maxPadding` for xAxis. This will work as long, as yod don't have scrolling/panning options enabled.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this. You can check the link again, i updated it with my results. Thanks a ton!